# Can white recover? (midgame)

Tags: analysis, middlegame

If someone could put a picture of the layout in that'd be great, I've looked (clicked edit) on posts with them and I cannot work out the format, also this is a setup, I didn't write down how I got there.

This is a game I was playing against my "Train board" on a train so not my finest work but I ended up in this situation and in the end "resigned" (turned it off), and what I've tried from here

```
[FEN "r4rk1/pp3ppp/2n1p3/q2p1b2/1b1PnB2/1QN2NPP/PP2PPB1/2R2RK1 w - - 0 1"]

1. g4 (1. Nxe4 dxe4 2. Ne5 Nxd4 {I've noted this was a good move for black, that I missed} 3. Qc4 (3. Qe3 Qd5 4. Qc3 Bxc3) Qd5 4. Qxb4 {play suspected trap for interest} (4. Qxd5 exd5 5. Rc7) Nxe2+) Bg6 2. Qa4 Nxc3 3. bxc3 {Stopped playing, loose queen} 0-1
```

Now I think (I wrote) that I opened very well and I seemed fairly happy with the moves before these, the move before this starts though I went from waiting room to train and I'm easily distracted by the scenery. So please no "idiot, who does that!" stuff.

I really think black has the stronger position by far, but the midgame can very easily turn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can white recover?

**White is just fine.** Sure, Black stands slightly better due to his **better coordinated** minor pieces, but the position is roughly equal.

> If someone could put a picture of the layout in that'd be great, I've
>   looked (clicked edit) on posts with them and I cannot work out the
>   format, also this is a setup, I didn't write down how I got there.

[This thread](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279/tool-used-to-create-chess-analysis-interactive-diagrams-in-many-chess-stack-exch/280#280) covers the topic pretty good in my opinion.

> I really think black has the stronger position by far, but the midgame can very easily turn.

I believe that opening went something like this:

```
[fen ""]

1.d4 d5 2.c4 c6 3.Nc3 Nf6 4.cxd5 cxd5 5.Bf4 Bf5 6.Nf3 Nc6 7.g3 e6 8.Qb3 Bb4 9.Bg2 O-O 10.O-O Qa5 11.Rac1 Ne4 12.Rfd1!?
```

Here, White's last move fortifies  the `d4` pawn, leaving `e2` pawn free which might be useful in some lines.

Sure, Black has aggressively posted minor pieces, but White **finished development** and is now ready to **push them back.** This means that Black will have to make exchanges which will reduce his pressure, or will have to fall back giving the initiative to White.

Therefore, I believe that the resulting position after `Rfd1!?` is unclear, with chances for both sides.

Since we look at this from White's perspective, it would be good if Black exchanged on `c3` and if White could then get Black's lightsquared bishop for `f3` knight. With a fortified `d4` pawn he could launch `e4` in appropriate moment in order to open his position for his bishops. In such position `Nc6` would be badly posted since `d4` pawn is fortified with `c3` pawn.

Just for an example, I provide a sample line:

```
[fen ""]

1.d4 d5 2.c4 c6 3.Nc3 Nf6 4.cxd5 cxd5 5.Bf4 Bf5 6.Nf3 Nc6 7.g3 e6 8.Qb3 Bb4 9.Bg2 O-O 10.O-O Qa5 11.Rac1 Ne4 12.Rfd1!? Rac8!? 13.Nh4 Nxc3 14.bxc3 Ba3 15.Ra1 Bg6 16.Nxg6 hxg6 17.e4+/=
```

Best regards.

Comment: I am glad I posted because I really enjoyed reading this answer! I've also learnt not to associate the feeling of being on guard with being in a bad position

Comment: @AlecTeal: I am glad I was helpful. Always look at the position objectively. If your plans did not fulfill that does not mean that you stand worse, it just means that things have changed. **This is normal in chess**, all you have to do is **take a fresh look on the resulting position and devise a new plan**.  Best regards.